# "The railways" or "the railway" or "railways"

Tags: definite-article, grammatical-number

Here are 2 examples in my grammar book, and it says that we use "the+plural noun" when we talk about a group as a whole:

1. It is difficult for railways to make a profit. (any railways).
2. The railways are getting more and more unreliable (our well-know railways).

I have a question about the 2nd sentence.
Is it correct to use "the+ plural noun" to talk about railways of a city or railways in the world in general as below. Which sentences below are correct to use?

---

1A. **Railways** in my city are getting more and more unreliable, compared to **airplanes** in my city.

1B. **The railways** in my city are getting more and more unreliable, compared to **the airplanes** in my city.

---

2A. **Railways** in the world are getting more and more unreliable, compared to **airplanes** (in the world).

2B. **The railways** in the world are getting more and more unreliable, compared to **the airplanes** (in the world).

---

3A. **The railway** in the world are getting more and more unreliable, compared to **the airplane** in the world.

Answer (score 2):

Sentences 1A and 1B are both fine. By including the definite article, 1B addresses the railways and airplanes more specifically. (I'll ignore the fact that airplanes don't usually remain in a single city.)

Sentences 2A and 2B sound unnatural because we don't say "in the world" like that. They would be acceptable if, for example, you changed the preposition "in" to "throughout".

Sentence 3A is incorrect. It doesn't make sense (because there is not a single railway or a single airplane in the world), and the grammmar is wrong (because a singular subject normally requires a singular verb).

Comment: 1A and 1B would make more sense as 'in my country', wouldn't they?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes. The railways in a specific city e.g. the underground systems in London or Paris are not often referred to as "railways" - though that is what they are. In London it's "the tube", in Paris "the metro".

Comment: You said “ 1B addresses the railways and airplanes more specifically.” But I still don’t understand what u mean. Can you help me clarify it?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, that would probably make more sense, although "in my city" is certainly possible if it's a large city with railways.

Comment: @LEHANH One of the main purposes of the definite article is to refer to specific items. This issue has been discussed elsewhere on ELL; have you done any research on it? What did you find?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I already know that the definite arrticle is to refer to specific items (example: the nurses in my hospital, the students in my school...), but In my sentence I refer to trains in general (in my country or in the world), not the specific trains. I don't understand that when i can use "the+plural noun" for general statements like this.

Comment: @LEHANH I don't really understand the confusion. As you say, "the definite arrticle is to refer to specific items". Therefore, if you just want to refer to trains in general, you wouldn't use the definite article.

Comment: The railways throughout the world are getting more and more unreliable, compared to the airplanes. This sentence is correct. Right? If so, we use" the" here to talk about unspecific railways, not ones we know.

Comment: @LEHANH No, you are talking about specific railways: the ones throughout the world. (Whether you know the railways or not is a separate issue. I could say "the king of Spain probably speaks Spanish" even though I don't know who that is.)